# Set target for switch in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, memory-leaks, delegates, uiswitch

I have a custom cell with a switch. I want to add the targets in `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`. But by doing so (in example code) I'll create a strong reference cycle.

Then I tried using a protocol / delegate method but that means all the cells will call the same method.

How can I setup my cells and add the targets accordingly?

---

Strong reference cycle:

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {
    var customSwitch: UISwitch()

    // setup switch
}

class VC1: UITableViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

            cell.customSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch1), for: valueChanged)

            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

            cell.customSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch2), for: valueChanged)

            return cell
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    @objc func handleSwitch1(_ sender: UISwitch) { }
    @objc func handleSwitch2(_ sender: UISwitch) { }
}
```

---

Using a delegate:

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {
    var customSwitch: UISwitch()
    weak var delegate: VC1Delegate?

    // setup switch

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        customSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch), for: valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func handleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate?.handleSwitch1(sender)
    }
}

protocol VC1Delegate: class {
    func handleSwitch1(_ sender: UISwitch)
    func handleSwitch2(_ sender: UISwitch)
}

class VC1: UITableViewController, VC1Delegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

            cell.delegate = self

            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

            cell.delegate = self

            return cell
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    @objc func handleSwitch1(_ sender: UISwitch) { }
    @objc func handleSwitch2(_ sender: UISwitch) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code marked "Strong reference cycle" there is no strong reference cycle, so just go ahead and use it.

Where did you imagine the strong reference cycle was? Was it the use of `self` as the `target`? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) say explicitly:

> The control does not retain the object in the target parameter

And that is only to be expected. We'd all be in a fine pickle if you couldn't set `self` as the action target for a control.

Comment: Thanks. The strong reference cycle is probably caused by something else in my code. My mistake, I thought this was causing it. Back to digging again!

Comment: No need to dig, if you have a leak you can find out instantly what it is. Use Memory Graph or Leaks instrument.